# How to run a full test suite with Appium, Selenium Grid, and an emulator on an EC2 machine without KVM?

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-compose, android-emulator, appium, selenium-grid

I want to launch a docker-compose file on an EC2 machine with Appium server, Selenium Grid, autotests, and an emulator. However, the budtmo-docker-android emulator requires KVM, which is not available on my EC2 instance. Is there a workaround to launch the Appium server, Selenium Grid, autotests, and an emulator without KVM?

One possibility I am considering is running the emulator separately from the docker-compose file or using cloud solutions like Genymotion.

I've tried to launch the emulator externally using scripts, and not in the docker container, but I'm not sure how to connect my Appium server to the emulator that runs outside the docker-compose file but on the same system.

How can I achieve this setup on an EC2 instance without KVM support?